# Read/Write usb hid device (with one interface type keyboard and mouse) on android

Tags: android, keyboard, usb, hid

I have a project where I have to communicate between an android application and a usb device. This device has a hid descriptor with different interfaces (5). There are one interface type "keyboard" and one interface type "mouse", other interface are undefined type. I have to read and write data from/to the device. I have seen the USB Host API can open a connection with a USB Device, but I can't see the device on android hid device list. I have seen that "USBManager.getDeviceList" doesn't return all the time keyboard. I think it's because there is still a handle open with this device. How can I prevent this handle ? How can I open get my device to open UsbDeviceConnection ?

For information : 
- When I plug my usb device :
           - it recognized as a keyboard (I can use key and navigate on interface)
           - I see the new file event on /dev/input 
- I use android 4.2.2 
           - dmesg :

> input: XXX   USB HID SENSORS as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.1/usb8/8-1/8-1:1.0/input/input29 
>   hid-generic 0003:2804:0100.0014: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [XXX   USB HID SENSORS] on usb-0000:00:10.1-1/input0 
>   input: XXX   USB HID SENSORS as > /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.1/usb8/8-1/8-1:1.1/input/input30 
>   hid-generic 0003:2804:0100.0015: input,hidraw4: USB HID v1.10 Device [XXX   USB HID SENSORS] on usb-0000:00:10.1-1/input1 
>    hid-generic 0003:2804:0100.0016: hiddev0,hidraw5: USB HID v1.10 Device [XXX   USB HID SENSORS] on usb-0000:00:10.1-1/input2 
>   input: XXX   USB HID SENSORS as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.1/usb8/8-1/8-1:1.3/input/input31 
>   hid-generic 0003:2804:0100.0017: input,hidraw6: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [XXX   USB HID SENSORS] on  usb-0000:00:10.1-1/input3 
>   hid-generic 0003:2804:0100.0018: hiddev0,hidraw7: USB HID v1.10 Device [XXX   USB HID SENSORS] on usb-0000:00:10.1-1/input4

Thank you for your help

Comment: aoa2.0 hid send to android 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016382/android-aoa-2-0-hid-keyboard


How to fix?

Answer (score 0):

I think the linux hid driver hooks on to the HID class, which prevents you from accessing the device from the application layer.

Why not have a look at [Android Open Accessory Protocol 2.0](https://source.android.com/accessories/aoa2.html). Perhaps, this could help you out in your venture.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have already seen Andrdoid Open Accessory Protocol but I haven't understand how I can use it. Have you some example ?

Comment: Check out https://android.googlesource.com/device/google/accessory/arduino/+/master/AndroidAccessory/

Comment: After lot of reading about AOA, I don't understand how can I can set up the AOA Protocol. All document I read use arduino. If I understand I have to create an object "accessory" but I don't understand what is this object. Should be place on otehr device between keyboard and android device ?